# How to fix the compilation error in anonymous PL/SQL block?

Tags: oracle, plsql

**Code:**

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
  SUM  NUMBER;
  tot  NUMBER;
  tata NUMBER;
  benz NUMBER;
  FUNCTION accident
    RETURN NUMBER
  IS
    z NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(rid)
    INTO tata
    FROM participatedin,
      Car
    WHERE car.cid=participatedin.cid
    AND model    ='honda';
    SELECT COUNT(rid)
    INTO benz
    FROM participatedin,
      Car
    WHERE car.cid=participatedin.cid
    AND model    ='benz';
    SUM         :=tata+benz;
    RETURN SUM;
  END;
BEGIN
  tot:=accident();
  dbms_output.put_line("Honda+Benz= "||tot);
END;
/
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR at line 19:
ORA-06550: line 19, column 11:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
(
```

Comment: You should give a more descriptive title so that people are more likely to look at your question.

Comment: `sum` is a function name, I imagine that's confusing the parser. Call your variable something else (and maybe declare it inside the function, along with `tata` and `benz`, instead of the unused `z`? seems more appropriate) and see if that resolves it. Your `dbms_output` will then error because you have double-quotes instead of single-quotes.

Comment: As Alex says, variables `tata` and `benz` are not in the scope of the function but you use them. Declare them in function declaration.

Comment: @FlorinGhita No, it is not about the scope of variables, the issue is that the variable `Honda` is of no use and not declared. And another issue is with the syntax in `dbms_output` i.e. incorrect use of quotes.

Comment: @YuviJum Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please go through the [**Stack Overflow tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand how this site works. I have edited your question title and body to make it understandable. Please do so yourself in future. All the best!

Comment: @LalitKumarB, Yes, you are right. The variables of the block can be manipulated with the function. I've seen your answer that points more errors and that's why I've voted it.

Comment: It's not mandatory to make your PL/SQL look like COBOL. You can use ordinary lower case and occasional blank lines just like other modern programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your **anonymous PL/SQL block**:

1. `SUM  NUMBER;`

**SUM** is a **reserved word** in PL/SQL. You cannot directly use it. Either use double-quotation marks to make it a quoted-identifier, or use a different name.

To see reserved words, do `help reserved words` in **SQL*Plus**:

```
SQL> help reserved words

 RESERVED WORDS (PL/SQL)
 -----------------------

 PL/SQL Reserved Words have special meaning in PL/SQL, and may not be used
 for identifier names (unless enclosed in "quotes").

 An asterisk (*) indicates words are also SQL Reserved Words.

 ALL*            DESC*           JAVA            PACKAGE         SUBTYPE
 ALTER*          DISTINCT*       LEVEL*          PARTITION       SUCCESSFUL*
 AND*            DO              LIKE*           PCTFREE*        SUM
 ANY*            DROP*           LIMITED         PLS_INTEGER     SYNONYM*
 ARRAY           ELSE*           LOCK*           POSITIVE        SYSDATE*
 AS*             ELSIF           LONG*           POSITIVEN       TABLE*
 ASC*            END             LOOP            PRAGMA          THEN*
 AT              EXCEPTION       MAX             PRIOR*          TIME
 AUTHID          EXCLUSIVE*      MIN             PRIVATE         TIMESTAMP
 AVG             EXECUTE         MINUS*          PROCEDURE       TIMEZONE_ABBR
 BEGIN           EXISTS*         MINUTE          PUBLIC*         TIMEZONE_HOUR
 BETWEEN*        EXIT            MLSLABEL*       RAISE           TIMEZONE_MINUTE
 BINARY_INTEGER  EXTENDS         MOD             RANGE           TIMEZONE_REGION
 BODY            EXTRACT         MODE*           RAW*            TO*
 BOOLEAN         FALSE           MONTH           REAL            TRIGGER*
 BULK            FETCH           NATURAL         RECORD          TRUE
 BY*             FLOAT*          NATURALN        REF             TYPE
 CHAR*           FOR*            NEW             RELEASE         UI
 CHAR_BASE       FORALL          NEXTVAL         RETURN          UNION*
 CHECK*          FROM*           NOCOPY          REVERSE         UNIQUE*
 CLOSE           FUNCTION        NOT*            ROLLBACK        UPDATE*
 CLUSTER*        GOTO            NOWAIT*         ROW*            USE
 COALESCE        GROUP*          NULL*           ROWID*          USER*
 COLLECT         HAVING*         NULLIF          ROWNUM*         VALIDATE*
 COMMENT*        HEAP            NUMBER*         ROWTYPE         VALUES*
 COMMIT          HOUR            NUMBER_BASE     SAVEPOINT       VARCHAR*
 COMPRESS*       IF              OCIROWID        SECOND          VARCHAR2*
 CONNECT*        IMMEDIATE*      OF*             SELECT*         VARIANCE
 CONSTANT        IN*             ON*             SEPERATE        VIEW*
 CREATE*         INDEX*          OPAQUE          SET*            WHEN
 CURRENT*        INDICATOR       OPEN            SHARE*          WHENEVER*
 CURRVAL         INSERT*         OPERATOR        SMALLINT*       WHERE*
 CURSOR          INTEGER*        OPTION*         SPACE           WHILE
 DATE*           INTERFACE       OR*             SQL             WITH*
 DAY             INTERSECT*      ORDER*          SQLCODE         WORK
 DECIMAL*        INTERVAL        ORGANIZATION    SQLERRM         WRITE
 DECLARE         INTO*           OTHERS          START*          YEAR
 DEFAULT*        IS*             OUT             STDDEV          ZONE
 DELETE*         ISOLATION
```

2. `dbms_output.put_line(tata+Benz ||' = '||tot);`

That is incorrect syntax. You need to leave the **variables** and use **single-quotation marks** only for **strings**.

3. `"Honda+Benz= "`

Variable `Honda` is not declared. Looking at your code, perhaps, you wanted to use `tata`.

Try the modified code:

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
  v_sum NUMBER;
  tot   NUMBER;
  tata  NUMBER;
  benz  NUMBER;
  FUNCTION accident
    RETURN NUMBER
  IS
    z NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(rid)
    INTO tata
    FROM participatedin,
      Car
    WHERE car.cid=participatedin.cid
    AND model    ='honda';
    SELECT COUNT(rid)
    INTO benz
    FROM participatedin,
      Car
    WHERE car.cid=participatedin.cid
    AND model    ='benz';
    v_sum       :=tata+benz;
    RETURN v_sum;
  END;
BEGIN
  tot:=accident();
  dbms_output.put_line(tata+Benz ||' = '||tot);
END;
/
```

**Working demo** using standard `EMP` table in SCOTT schema:

```
SQL> SET serveroutput ON;
SQL> DECLARE
  2    v_sum NUMBER;
  3    tot   NUMBER;
  4    tata  NUMBER;
  5    benz  NUMBER;
  6    FUNCTION accident
  7      RETURN NUMBER
  8    IS
  9      z NUMBER;
 10    BEGIN
 11      SELECT COUNT(empno)
 12      INTO tata
 13      FROM emp;
 14      SELECT COUNT(empno)
 15      INTO benz
 16      FROM emp;
 17      v_sum       :=tata+benz;
 18      RETURN v_sum;
 19    END;
 20  BEGIN
 21    tot:=accident();
 22    dbms_output.put_line('tata+Benz = '||tot);
 23  END;
 24  /
tata+Benz = 28

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to change parameter **"SUM"**, as it is a function in Oracle. If you change it to something else, code will work.
see the changed code below :

```
DECLARE
  sum1 NUMBER;
  tot  NUMBER;
  tata NUMBER;
  benz NUMBER;
  FUNCTION accident RETURN NUMBER IS
    z NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(rid)
      INTO tata
      FROM participatedin, car
     WHERE car.cid = participatedin.cid
       AND model = 'honda';
    SELECT COUNT(rid)
      INTO benz
      FROM participatedin, car
     WHERE car.cid = participatedin.cid
       AND model = 'benz';
    sum1 := tata + benz;
    RETURN sum1;
  END;
BEGIN
  tot := accident();
  dbms_output.put_line('Honda+Benz= ' || tot);
END;
/
```